# I have problem using optirun

Tags: drivers, nvidia, xorg, nvidia-optimus, bumblebee

I run

```
optirun -vv glxgears
```

got

```
[  649.857041] [DEBUG]Reading file: /etc/bumblebee/bumblebee.conf
[  649.857239] [INFO]Configured driver: nvidia
[  649.857327] [DEBUG]optirun version 3.2.1 starting...
[  649.857339] [DEBUG]Active configuration:
[  649.857347] [DEBUG] bumblebeed config file: /etc/bumblebee/bumblebee.conf
[  649.857355] [DEBUG] X display: :8
[  649.857363] [DEBUG] LD_LIBRARY_PATH: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/nvidia:/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/nvidia:/usr/lib/nvidia
[  649.857372] [DEBUG] Socket path: /var/run/bumblebee.socket
[  649.857380] [DEBUG] Accel/display bridge: auto
[  649.857388] [DEBUG] VGL Compression: proxy
[  649.857395] [DEBUG] VGLrun extra options: 
[  649.857404] [DEBUG] Primus LD Path: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/primus:/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/primus:/usr/lib/primus:/usr/lib32/primus
[  649.857439] [DEBUG]Using auto-detected bridge primus
[  649.863457] [INFO]Response: No - error: [XORG] (EE) 
[  649.863470] [ERROR]Cannot access secondary GPU - error: [XORG] (EE) 
[  649.863474] [DEBUG]Socket closed.
[  649.863485] [ERROR]Aborting because fallback start is disabled.
[  649.863488] [DEBUG]Killing all remaining processes.
```

my `bumblebee.conf` is set that

```
Driver=nvidia
KernelDriver=nvidia-current
```

I have

```
08:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GK107M [GeForce GT 750M] (rev a1)
```

and in `xorg.conf.nvidia` I have

```
BusID "PCI:08:00:0"
```

and I have

```
Mar 05 06:45:48 us bumblebeed[768]: [  452.390810] [ERROR][XORG] (EE)
Mar 05 06:45:48 us bumblebeed[768]: [  452.391223] [ERROR][XORG] (EE)
Mar 05 06:45:48 us bumblebeed[768]: [  452.391455] [ERROR][XORG] (EE)
Mar 05 06:45:48 us bumblebeed[768]: [  452.391668] [ERROR][XORG] (EE)
Mar 05 06:45:48 us bumblebeed[768]: [  452.391883] [ERROR][XORG] (EE)
Mar 05 06:45:48 us bumblebeed[768]: [  452.392028] [ERROR]X did not start properly
```

Does someone know the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Use the newest NVIDIA drivers and `nvidia-prime` from Ubuntu repositories.

Bumblebee was replaced by `nvidia-prime` to switch between the graphics.

---

**1. Remove all NVIDIA related software you have installed.**

Open a terminal and execute:

```
sudo apt-get purge nvidia* bumblebee
sudo reboot
```

**2. Install the NVIDIA drivers 352 and Optimus support.**

Open a terminal and execute:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-352 nvidia-prime
sudo reboot
```

**3. Switch between Intel and NVIDIA graphics**.

Open **<kbd>NVIDIA X Server Settings</kbd> → <kbd>PRIME Profiles</kbd>**.

Comment: I forgot to mention that i am now using debian sid, and i think that nvidia-prime has not yet been added to debian.

Comment: why debian sid had no such packages?? how can i add the source to source.list? thank you!

Comment: @YuriHemizakov : Unfortunately debian is off-topic here and I can't tell you why debian does not include nvidia-prime in their repositories - so you should ask this the debian packages maintainer or on a debian forum. :)